# How to Build a UnitOfWork Scoped Object Graph within Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

Our web sites are currently using Ninject; however, we are looking at moving to SimpleInjector (since our tests show a 26% speed increase). However, we can't get the DbContext's scoping to work correctly.

Here's a simple version of our Unit Of Work model (in shorthand):

```
class MyDbContext : EfDbContext, IStore, ICommitStorage 

interface IRepoFactor
    IRepoUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork();

class MyRepoUnitOfWork : RepoUnitOfWorkBase
    MyRepoUnitOfWork(Container container, ICommitStorage dbContext)
        : base(dbContext) {
        _lazyLoadDto1= new Lazy<Dto1Repo>(container.GetInstance<Dto1Repo>);
        _lazyLoadDto2= new Lazy<Dto2Repo>(containe.GetInstance<Dto2Repo>);
    }

    Dto1Repo Dto1 => _lazyLoadDto1.Value;
    Dto2Repo Dto2 => _lazyLoadDto2.Value;
    etc...

class Dto1Repo : Repository<Dto1>
    Dto1Repo(IStore dbContext) {...}

class Dto2Repo : Repository<Dto2>
    Dto2Repo(IStore dbContext) {...}
```

We want the same `MyDbContext` that was created for `MyRepoUnitOfWork` to be shared across all the Repository classes that the `MyRepoUnitOfWork` class owns.

Currently our configuration looks something like this:

```
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    container.Register<IRepoFactory, MyRepoFactory>();
    container.Register<MyRepoUnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    var dbContextReg = Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(() => new MyDbContext("(local)"), container);
    container.AddRegistration<IStore>(dbContextReg);
    container.AddRegistration<ICommitStorage>(dbContextReg);
```

**Summary**

In a nutshell, we want to create a `scope` within `CreateUnitOfWork()` but dispose of the `scope` within the `MyRepoUnitOfWork` object. Something like:

```
public MyRepoUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork(object args = null)
{
    var scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_resolver);
    return _resolver.GetInstance<MyRepoUnitOfWork>(scope);
}
```

But we aren't sure how to pass the scope variable into the `MyRepoUnitOfWork` object.

Any way to make this work? Or is there a better/different approach we aren't seeing?

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want to create a scope _within_ the factory method anf dispose it when the UoW is disposed? Why can't the UoW be scoped around the request? That would remove the need for the factory completely.

Comment: Originally we had it scoped at the request but our business logic required at times multiple independent UoWs. Therefore, we had to move the scope down a level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Property Injection instead:

```
public MyRepoUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork(object args = null)
{
    var scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_resolver);
    var uow = _resolver.GetInstance<MyRepoUnitOfWork>();
    uow.Scope = scope;
    return uow;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of this idea. Let me try it. Ideally it would be great if we could pass one or more ctor params or add an existing object to the container on the fly but I know you like to freeze the container on first access.

Comment: Okay, that worked but the very first 'real' application we started to convert needed to pass in an ID. Which is then passed into all the Repo objects. So, using a property is doable but messy. Therefore, we have decided to use a hybrid approach in these cases. I.e.:
`return new MyUnitOfWork(_resolver.GetInstance<ICommitStorage>(), _resolver.GetInstance<RepoContext>(), Id);`

Comment: Prevent injecting runtime data, such as Ids, into your application components during construction. As you already noticed, this leads to extra complexity, and that's why I consider [this to be a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).